# Unicode-aware strings(1) program

Tags: string, unicode

Does anybody have a code sample for a unicode-aware strings program?  Programming language doesn't matter.  I want something that essentially does the same thing as the unix command "strings", but that also functions on unicode text (UTF-16 or UTF-8), pulling runs of english-language characters and punctuation.  (I only care about english characters, not any other alphabet).

Thanks!

Comment: For english only and UTF-8, strings(1) should already be OK.

Comment: If the language doesn't matter then why don't you check the source of the strings utility itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you just want to use it, or do you for some reason insist on the code?

On my Debian system, it seems `strings` command can do this out of the box. See the exercept from the manpage:

```
  --encoding=encoding
       Select the character encoding of the strings that are to be found.  Possible values for encoding are: s = single-7-bit-byte characters (ASCII, ISO  8859,
       etc.,  default),  S  = single-8-bit-byte characters, b = 16-bit bigendian, l = 16-bit littleendian, B = 32-bit bigendian, L = 32-bit littleendian. Useful
       for finding wide character strings.
```

Edit: OK. I don't know C# so this may be a bit hairy, but basically, you need to search for sequences of alternating zeros and English characters.

```
byte b;
int i=0;
while(!endOfInput()) {
  b=getNextByte();
LoopBegin:
  if(!isEnglish(b)) {
    if(i>0) // report successful match of length i
    i=0;
    continue;
  }
  if(endOfInput()) break;
  if((b=getNextByte())!=0)
    goto LoopBegin;
  i++; // found another character
}
```

This should work for little-endian.

Comment: I need the code... I need to incorporate it in a system I'm writing (in c#, if it matters).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  Pretty obvious, now that I think about it; just skip the null bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and tried the "`strings -e ...`" but I just found options for fix width chars encoding. (UTF-8 encoding is variable width).

Remeber thar by default characters outside ascii need extra `strings` options. This includes almost all non English language strings.

Nevertheless "`-e S`" (single 8 bits chars) output includes UTF-8 chars.

I wrote a very simple (opinion-ed) Perl script that applies a 
  "`strings -e S ... | iconv ...`" to the input files.

I believe it is easy to tune it for specific restrictions. 
Usage: `utf8strings [options] file*`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

our ($all,$windows,$enc);   ## use -all ignore the "3 letters word" restriction
use strict;
use utf8::all;

$enc = "ms-ansi" if     $windows;  ##
$enc = "utf8"    unless $enc    ;  ## defaul encoding=utf8
my $iconv = "iconv -c -f $enc -t utf8 |";

for (@ARGV){ s/(.*)/strings -e S '$1'| $iconv/;}

my $word=qr/[a-zçáéíóúâêôàèìòùüãõ]{3}/i;   # adapt this to your case

while(<>){
   # next if /regular expressions for common garbage/; 
   print    if ($all or /$word/);
}
```

In some situations, this approach produce some extra garbage.